# Rails 3.0.10 - Nested route not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**Gists of controller code at bottom of page**

I have a simple rails nesting project that I'm practicing with and I'm having an issue that I can't seem to spot.

When I visit the url:  `localhost:3000/authors/1/books` I get ALL the books - not the books that correspond to the author with an id=1.

Here is some of my code:

I have an **Author** model and controller, and a **Book** author and controller:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end


class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

The routes file looks like this:

```
resources :authors do
    resources :books    
  end
```

Here is the migration for Books:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.integer :author_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :books
  end
end
```

It contains an attribute for **author_id**

I also have this code in the Books _form.html.erb file:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select(:author_id, Author.all, :id, :first_name) %>
  </div>
```

I am able to choose an author from the drop-down box and save it successfully.  The database shows that the author_id is indeed being saved to the corresponding Book model.

When I run **`rake routes`**  I get this as one of the routes:

```
author_books GET    /authors/:author_id/books(.:format)
```

But, when I try this url - I just get a listing of **ALL** books.  Not books corresponding to the proper author.

Also, I have my controllers setup to return JSON and when I put `localhost:3000/authors.json` it returns the proper JSON object, but when I put `localhost:3000/authors/1/books.json` it returns '**null**'

Here is a screen shot of my current database listings to show that the data is definitely there:

[image]

**Can you see anything that may be causing the problem???  I can provide more code if you need it.**

---

**EDIT**

After running `rails console` I get the correct data - so I'm not sure why the route is still not working:

```
irb(main):002:0> Author.find(1).books
=> [#<Book id: 1, title: "Carrie", author_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-08 21:20:57", updated_at: "201
2-01-08 21:20:57">]
```

**Here is a Gist of complete routes:** https://gist.github.com/1580058

**Here is the Books controller:** https://gist.github.com/1580064

**Here is the Authors controller:** https://gist.github.com/1580134

Sorry, just realized I miss-worded the original question up top - I'm getting the whole list of **Books**, not **Authors** - corrected

Comment: What happens when you open up a rails console and type `Author.find(1).books`? Can you show some controller code? Can you confirm that the query for all books is @author.books?

Comment: Can we see the controller code?

Comment: Can you also post **all** the routes (throw it in a Git gist if you want), just in case there's a conflict, or something strange going on? It would also be helpful to see the lines from the `development.log` file where the loading of `/authors/1/books` was done, so we can see which views/actions were actually called and rendered.

Comment: +1 for controller code. Specifically the `index` action in the books controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show us your index action in the controller. I'm guessing you have Book.all... You need

```
@author = Author.includes(:books).find(params[:author_id])
```

you also might want

```
@books = @author.books
```

Also in your show method make sure you do this

```
@author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
@book = @author.books.find(params[:id])
```

instead of

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I included the Gists of my controller code in the EDIT section on the bottom of my question.  I tried your code, but now when I go to the url I get this: undefined method `books' for nil:NilClass.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry - I had one of the lines switched.  I needed your modified author instance variable listed before the books variable.  Thanks for your help!